# Does Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack (MDOP) 2010 require an AD schema change

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows, app-v

Does App-V 4.6 from MDOP 2010 require any AD schema changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. None of the MDOP programs have Schema Changes.